Convert Datatable to Word
I have this code that is converting a datatable received as a parameter into a Microsoft Word application, the code is used inside a website.
It is called by simply clicking an Export to MS Word button.
Public Shared Sub ConvertToWord(ByVal WebHttpResponse As System.Web.HttpResponse, ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal reportTitle As String, Optional ByVal FileName As String = "FileName")
        WebHttpResponse.Clear()
        WebHttpResponse.Charset = ""
        WebHttpResponse.ContentType = "application/msword"

        Dim dg As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView()
        dg.DataSource = dt
        dg.DataBind()

        dg.Font.Name = "Arial"
        dg.Font.Size = 9
        dg.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.None
        dg.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#4A3C8C")
        dg.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#F7F7F7")
        dg.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        dg.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#F7F7F7")
        dg.RowStyle.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#E7E7FF")
        dg.RowStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#4A3C8C")
        dg.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = True
        dg.GridLines = System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridLines.Horizontal
        dg.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        dg.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#E7E7FF")
        WebHttpResponse.Buffer = True
        WebHttpResponse.ClearContent()
        WebHttpResponse.ClearHeaders()
        WebHttpResponse.ContentType = "application/msword"
        WebHttpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= " & FileName & ".doc")
        Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)
        dg.RenderControl(hw)
        WebHttpResponse.Write("Created on: " & DateTime.Now.ToString() & "<BR>")
        If reportTitle <> "" Then
            WebHttpResponse.Write("<BR><b><center><font size=3 face=Verdana color=#0000FF>" & reportTitle & "</font></center></b><BR>")
        End If
        WebHttpResponse.Write(tw.ToString())
        WebHttpResponse.Flush()
        WebHttpResponse.Close()
        WebHttpResponse.[End]()
    End Sub

Any suggestions?
